# problem with python "requests" in a PyQt5 QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, pyqt5, qthread

In my program i use `PyQt5` for the Gui, `selenium` and `requests`.
My programm should do some tests at the start.
For the first it checks if the edgeDriver the right one for the msEdge-version
then it checks the internetconnection with requests
and if all OK it opens the Edge browser with selenium.

i wrote a testscript and all works fine but if i make the small necessary changes to use this script in a `QThread` to prevent freezing the GUI i get a whole bunch of errors like `ConnectionError`, `ConnectionRefuseError`, `ProxyError` and so on.
it would be very nice if someone could tell me, what is the problem here.
it has to come from request, because the other parts which not need the request work even fine.

Why the script works if i start it with `__main__` but not in a `QThread`.

Here is my Example class.
I comment out these changes which i made for the QThread.

**`test.py`**

```
from genericpath import exists
from win32api import *
# Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# Selenium Exceptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import os, os.path, requests, time
from zipfile import ZipFile
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread


HTTP_PROXY  = "http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/localproxy-xxxxxxxx.pac"
GOOGLE = r'https://www.google.de/'

PROXIES = { 
              "http"  : HTTP_PROXY, 
              "https" : HTTP_PROXY, 
            }
TARGET_PATH = 'webdriver\\' 
TARGET_NAME = 'driver.exe'
DRIVERPATH = r"webdriver\driver.exe"
EDGEPATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
HEADER = headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.39',
}


class Example():
#class Example(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        #super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.driverDownloadLink = None
        self._parent= parent
        self.google = GOOGLE
        self.driver = None
        self.edgeVersion = None
        self.driverVersion = None
        self.service = Service(DRIVERPATH)
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.options.headless = False
        self.wait = None


    def downloadDriver(self, url):
        try:
            req = requests.get(url, proxies=PROXIES)
        except:
            req = requests.get(url)
            if req.status_code == 200:
                dlFileName = req.url[req.url.rfind('/')+1:]
                with open('webdriver\\'+dlFileName,'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        if chunk:
                            f.write(chunk)
                with ZipFile('webdriver\\' + dlFileName) as zippedFile:
                    fileInfo = zippedFile.infolist()
                    for file in fileInfo:
                        if file.filename.find('.exe') >= 0:
                            filename = file.filename
                            zippedFile.extract(file,'webdriver\\tmp')
                os.replace('webdriver\\tmp\\'+filename, f'webdriver\{TARGET_NAME}')
                os.rmdir('webdriver\\tmp')
                os.remove('webdriver\\' + dlFileName)
            else:
                return False

    #def run(self):
    def driverCompatibility(self):
        if exists(EDGEPATH):
            self.edgeVersion = '.'.join(self.get_fileVersion(EDGEPATH))
            self.driverDownloadLink = f'https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/{self.edgeVersion}/edgedriver_win64.zip'
            if exists(DRIVERPATH):
                self.driverVersion = '.'.join(self.get_fileVersion(DRIVERPATH))
            else:
                self.downloadDriver(self.driverDownloadLink)
                #return self.run()
                return self.driverCompatibility()
        else:
            return False
        if self.driverVersion == self.edgeVersion:
            return True
        else:
            self.downloadDriver(self.driverDownloadLink)
            #return self.run()
            return self.driverCompatibility()

    def get_fileVersion(self, filePath):
        File_information = GetFileVersionInfo(filePath, "\\")
        ms_file_version = File_information['FileVersionMS']
        ls_file_version = File_information['FileVersionLS']
        return  [str(HIWORD(ms_file_version)), str(LOWORD(ms_file_version)),
                str(HIWORD(ls_file_version)), str(LOWORD(ls_file_version))]


    def buildConnection(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge(service=self.service, options=self.options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        try:
            self.driver.get(GOOGLE)
            print('You are on google webpage')
        except WebDriverException:
            print('Ooops...Something went wrong')    
        finally:
            time.sleep(5)
            self.driver.quit()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    network = Example()
    if network.driverCompatibility():
        print('All OK')
        network.buildConnection()
    else:
        print('Nope')
```

In my PyQt5 Mainwindow script i did the following:

I use the commented out parts in the script above and in my mainWindow.py

```
self.T = QThread(self)
self.E = Example()
self.E.start()
```

Maybe there is a better way to use threads nevertheless it should work.
Thank you

**These are the `exceptions`:**
Some of them are in German and means

*A connection could not be established because the target computer refused the connection*

```
C:\Users\fl4l\Documents\Python_Projects\PLT>main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028699AED3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='msedgedriver.azureedge.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /101.0.1210.53/edgedriver_win64.zip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028699AED3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\Documents\Python_Projects\PLT\test.py", line 52, in downloadDriver
    req = requests.get(url, proxies=PROXIES)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='msedgedriver.azureedge.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /101.0.1210.53/edgedriver_win64.zip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028699AED3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\fl4l\Documents\Python_Projects\PLT\test.py", line 81, in run
    self.downloadDriver(self.driverDownloadLink)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\Documents\Python_Projects\PLT\test.py", line 54, in downloadDriver
    req = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fl4l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='msedgedriver.azureedge.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /101.0.1210.53/edgedriver_win64.zip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002869C112190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte')))
```

What I absolutely cannot understand is that these errors only occur if the requests run in a separate thread.

Comment: Why haven't you shown the actual errors?

Comment: Because it was a lot of text :-) Wait a second i will edit my post

Comment: The tracebacks don't seem to correspond with how (in your question) you say you run the test (i.e. via mainWindow.py). So you have not provided an [mre].

Comment: Ah sorry. I thought it was clear enough. I will provide shortly

Comment: Ideally, your example should eliminate all unnecessary imports and avoid being platform-specific, if that's possible (i.e. still reproducible).

Comment: I will do my best :-)

Comment: I've been trying to solve the problem all day yesterday but then i realized there is no problem with my code. i tried my script on another computer and all works fine. then i simplified my code and test it on my computer again and there are the errors again. it seems, that anything is wrong with my connection or something link that. Everytime i make a request.get(),i get the error that the target computer refused the connection. All things like chrome, edge whatever works fine. surfing, downloading all works. what could be the problem if my code works fine on another computer, but not on mine?

Comment: It looks like only you can really answer that at the moment, since it seems highly unlikely that anyone else will be able to reproduce it. You must use trial and error to eliminate elements in your current test-case one by one until you pinpoint the source of the problem. It appears there may be a bug in one of the libraries you are using that is platform- and/or version-specific. But at the moment, you don't even know which component is involved. This is why it is vital to reduce your test-case to a truly *minimal* reproducible example.

Comment: Mmhh. I work with 2 Computer. One at home the other one at work. Both use same libs and same code. But my home computer use Win 11 and the other one use Win 10. Maybe there is the problem. I dont know. The good thing is, that the software i write will be used at work and there all works fine. Puuhh ;-) But this is definitly a point to check in the future. Thank you.

Comment: I could solve the problem by setting the proxies in dict to None. But i dont unterstand why the connection still failed, although i also tried without set the proxies-parameter. Mmhh strange. Not matter...Now it works